# how to add two files and save into another file using python

Tags: python

input1:

```
create external table db.emp(id int,name string)
row formatted fields terminated by ','
location 'hadfs:.../';

create external table db.emp1(id int,name string)
row formatted fields terminated by ','
location 'hadfs:.../';
```

input2:

```
create  table db.emp(id int,name string)
location 'hadfs:.../';;
create table db.emp1(id int,name string)
location 'hadfs:.../';
```

requeried output:

```
create external table db.emp(id int,name string)
row formatted fields terminated by ','
location 'hadfs:.../';
create table db.emp(id int,name string)
location 'hadfs:.../';
```

these two files stored under file1.hql

---

```
create external table db.emp1(id int,name string)
row formatted fields terminated by ','
location 'hadfs:.../';
create  table db.emp1(id int,name string)
location 'hadfs:.../';
```

These two files stored under file2.hql and so on

```
filenames = ['in1.txt', 'in2.txt']
with open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile:
  for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname) as infile:
       content = infile.read().replace('\n', '')
        outfile.write(content)
```

but i didn't get the correct output. Please give me a hint how to achieve this.
While using this code am getting output incorrect mannaer

I tried with code

```
import re
import sys
f = open ('text.txt','r')
fout = open ('hql.txt','w')
text = f.read()
fout = "hql.txt"
fout = open('hql.txt','w')
for item in re.findall(r'CREATE[^;]*;',text):
      print >>fout, re.search(r'(?<=\.)\w+',item).group()+'.hql'
      print >>fout,(item)

 f.close()
 fout.close()
```

the o/p of this code is :

```
emp.hql
create external table db.emp(id int,name string)
row formatted fields terminated by ','
location 'hadfs:.../';

emp1.hql

create external table db.emp(id int,name string)
row formatted fields terminated by ','
location 'hadfs:.../';
```

it will generate this kind of output to the both input1 and input2 files.
Now i need to concat

```
create external table db.emp(id int,name string)
row formatted fields terminated by ','
location 'hadfs:.../';
create table db.emp(id int,name string)
location 'hadfs:.../';
```

and stored in file as emp.hql and so on.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation

Comment: Please verify the indentation and also clarify and show part of the incorrect output, and the reason of stripping '\n' instead of '\n\n'.

Comment: `outfile.write(content)` line is not properly indented. Well, it is. But if you want to achieve your desired output, it shouldn't be indented like that. Please verify

Answer (score 2):

Whith this indentation all works fine:

```
filenames = ['in1.txt', 'in2.txt']
with open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            content = infile.read().replace('\n', '')
            outfile.write(content)
```

And take care of the order of recording files. You can use tuple `filenames = ('in1.txt', 'in2.txt')` for recording first the in1.txt and then the in2.txt.

Answer (score 0):

The aim here is to read 4 lines from `input1` and 2 lines from `input2`, remove any blank lines, and write these lines sequentially into an output file.

To do this, a [`grouper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice#recipes) function can be used which will read each of the files in suitable chunks. The `zip()` is used to get both groups of data together at the same time.

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

with open('in1.txt') as f_1, open('in2.txt') as f_2:
    for file_number, rows in enumerate(zip(grouper(f_1, 4, ''), grouper(f_2, 2, '')), start=1):
        # Remove carriage returns and empty lines from all rows
        rows = [[row.strip() for row in r if len(row.strip())] for r in rows]

        with open('file{}.hql'.format(file_number), 'w') as f_output:
            f_output.write('{}\n{}\n'.format('\n'.join(rows[0]), '\n'.join(rows[1])))
```

Giving you `file1.hql` looking as follows:

```
create external table db.emp(id int,name string)
row formatted fields terminated by ','
location 'hadfs:.../';
create  table db.emp(id int,name string)
location 'hadfs:.../';;
```

I suggest you add `print` statements to better understand what each line is doing.

Comment: while using this code i am getting every thing into one file but i want create external table db.emp(id int,name string)
row formatted fields terminated by ','
location 'hadfs:.../';
create  table db.emp(id int,name string)
location 'hadfs:.../';; into file1, and create external table db.emp1(id int,name string)
row formatted fields terminated by ','
location 'hadfs:.../';
create table db.emp1(id int,name string)
location 'hadfs:.../'; into file2 how can i add. Please assist me.

Comment: I tried with instead of taking with line first I make each table info into table.haql and then I tried to add two files. I tried with code

Comment: for item in re.findall(r'CREATE[^;]*;',text):
        print >>fout, re.search(r'(?<=\.)\w+',item).group()+'.hql'
        print >>fout,(item)

Comment: now the output is emp.hql under create external table db.emp(id int,name string)
row formatted fields terminated by ','
location 'hadfs:.../';now i need to add two files emp.hql how can i achieve

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please put REAL data examples into your question and the exact expected outputs.

Comment: Can anyone give me suggestions to achieve my required output.